# Chrome developer tool stopped showing page load time

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

From last few weeks, chrome has stopped showing page load time in network tab (metrics at bottom status bar).
I can still see them in Edge browser but not in chrome, please see screenshot attached from Edge.

Question is, do we have some hidden settings to enable these in chrome ? Why would google remove this option in new updates ?

[image]

Comment: Found a workaround by re-installing Chrome. It started showing Finish / DOMContentLoaded and Load time.